# How to use repeatedly non destructive Booleans

Tags: modifiers

I have 2 meshes, and I'm doing a a difference Boolean non destructive. I wanted to use the same Boolean, so I duplicated it, I can see the outline, but there is no other cut. I'd like to use the same Boolean to repeatedly if possible, rather than making using more meshes.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate in edit mode?

Comment: I was selecting the Boolean rather than the shape.  So it, worked selecting the Shape in edit more. Thanks.